# How to get variable in javascript to a python file?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-mail

I am looking to send a user an email. In order to do so, I need to get the user's email, which I have done with a javascript function:

```
function exportEmail() {
  var email = prompt("Please enter your email: ", "");

  if(email == null || email == "") {
    txt = "User cancelled a prompt";
  } else {
    txt = "An email will be sent to " + email;
  }
  
}
```

Which gets the user's email. I now want to send an email with flask-mail. Is there a way to get the variable that holds the user's email to the app.py python file?

I was also thinking that there might be a way to get the email in the python file to make it simpler, but I would like the prompt to come up on a button press, which is what currently happens via the javascript and html.

There may also be a better way to go about this that I did not think of, if so, how would I go about it?

Comment: You have to send [request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) on the backend that contains the email.

Comment: You need to send a request to your python backend server. You can use fetch API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API for this purpose.

Comment: Please add examples that you have tried in the python/flask that did not worked. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask